# Router not detecting VM Internal IP address

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

Details:

- Host OS: Windows 11 Home
- Guest OS: Windows 10 Pro
- VirtualBox Ver: 7.0.12
- Network Type: Bridge Adapter
- Router: Netgear

I am new to VirtualBox and networking in general. I am trying to setup an RDP connection into VM via VirtualBox. I want people over the internet to be able to remote into the VM.

Here's what I have done so far. I have successfully setup the VM for remote access using the built in Windows 10 Pro remote. I was able to RDP into it over LAN. I am now trying to port forward request to the ipv4 address on that port. However, when I attempt to do so in the router, it  states the internal ip address is not available. The firewall on the VM is completely disabled and I have confirmed that it is up through an IP scanner.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

**Showing internal ipv4 address and router port forwarding:**
[Image 1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/942218891952783421/1173342301276348516/image.png?ex=65639b2c&is=6551262c&hm=1b6d5267ca70e6c3ccbce0806f4d1b5b6286403be7a61259403814594603c4b9&)

**Showing firewall turned off and result screen:**
[Image 2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/942218891952783421/1173342417420820570/image.png?ex=65639b47&is=65512647&hm=94bdbbe8cb156df9703d1bae29f9e0d293d96ae2e887845e4d7ed49e01d1ee0e&)

Edit: Add images (apologies for not displaying them as I do not have enough reputation)

Comment: Try to : (1) disable the firewall on the host, (2) check that the MAC address of the VM is different from the host, (3) set the network type to NAT.

Comment: Normally the router wouldn't try to "detect" a host / IP when you try to set up port forwarding. (Because it doesn't make any sense exactly.) Can you add a screenshot of the setting page? Sounds more like you are fiddling the wrong setting to me (or passing in wrong params).

Comment: @harrymc `set the network type to NAT` Please re-read the context (and/or correct your typo).

Comment: @TomYan: What typo? I'm using the poster's terminology for his VirtualBox VM settings.

Comment: @harrymc It makes no sense to ask the OP to change the network type from Bridged to NAT in this context.

Comment: @TomYan: I have found that sometimes jogging the type between NAT and Bridged may unblock the situation. Afterward, returning to Bridged worked correctly for me in many cases. I don't have a good explanation why monkeying with the type helps.

Comment: Hello @TomYam. I have added images to provide better context. I will try harrymc's  workarounds and see if it works. Thank you all for responding!

Comment: As I've guessed, the internal IP does not appear to be within the router's LAN subnet (192.168.0.0/24). My guess is your VM and VM host are not directly connected to the Netgear but some other router (of which the WAN port is connected to the Netgear). While technically port forwarding can be set up on an "outer" router to a "inner" LAN host directly given the router has proper route configured for the "inner" subnet, consumer grade routers are usually too dumb / "safe" to allow such configuration. You'll need to try "double" port forward instead if it is the case.

Comment: Thank you for the help @TomYan. That was indeed the problem. I am actually connected to a mesh network. I tried doing a double port forwarding route but my router didn't end up detecting any of the ipv4 addresses on the network. I ended up putting the mesh in bridge mode which removed the double NAT effect. 

If you would like to write an answer, I would gladly accept it as the answer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Before you have it put into bridge mode, your mesh router should have a WAN IP, which would be an IP that belongs to the Netgear's LAN subnet. By "double" port forward I meant to enter the WAN IP of the mesh router (some 192.168.0.x) on the Netgear port forward setting, and then also port forward on your mesh router (where the VM's IP would be accepted). But yeah if you are fine with putting the mesh in bridge mode, that would work as well without the hassle.